# What have I done that causes the one face to be effected differently to the subsurf modifier?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

I must have done something to this face,edges or vertices that despite looking O.K. in wireframe mode is affected by the subsurf modifier. Can I correct it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you must have duplicated this face

Comment: .. that's right. there look to be 2 faces here, one of whose edges is split from the rest of the mesh. You should just be able to delete it.

Comment: @Robin Betts When I delete the face there is nothing there at all. I will upload file perhaps that might help? Thanks

Comment: That does sound strange... have you checked for edges marked 'Sharp'? is there an Edge Split modifier in there somewhere? ... I'll have a look

Comment: OK, it's just a detached face.( I thought the inside face behind it was in the same place.) You must have hit 'Y' while it was selected, or something like that. Anyway... Vertex Mode;  Select all; Ctrl-V (Vertex menu) > Remove Doubles.   ... Nicely modeled screw thread, BTW :)

Comment: @Robin Betts Thank you very much. I had tried to remove doubles but I was in face mode!!  Can't take credit for the screw thread that is way beyond my capabilities as yet!!

Comment: You can remove doubles from face mode, too; you just have to have all the vertices you want merged in your selection. There's a reason for that. Sometimes there are vertices in your model you _don't_ want merged which are closer to one another than other pairs of vertices you do want merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The face was in fact detached. At some point I must have used the Hotkey Y and split the face whilst the face was selected. According to the blender Manual this disconnects (splits) the selection from the rest of the mesh and the border edge to any non-selected elements are duplicated and the “copy” is left exactly at the same position as the original.
To fix this I used the Remove Doubles tool which according to the Blender Manual merges the selected vertices that are closer than a specified distance to each other.

In Vertex Mode, Select all, Ctrl-V (shortcut to Vertex menu), Remove Doubles.

This answer was in fact provided by Robin Betts in the comments section. Many thanks to him.

[image]